# Batik + debug information

Tags: java, svg, batik

I am trying to debug batik functionality via eclipse.
And I'm getting next error:

```
Unable to install breakpoint ... batik_class_name_here due to missing line number attributes.
```

Looks like main batik distribution (http://archive.apache.org/dist/xmlgraphics/batik/) didn't include debug information during compiling (-g flag).

Where I can find correct distribution with line numbers information? 
Or only one way: compile my own distribution?

Comment: I can able to bug with the source code directly taken from apache site. this my modified repo https://github.com/PraveenRavipati/ApacheBatik